# Azure Resources not showing up in VS Code, under the Azure Tools tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I may have disabled it some time ago, because it wasn't working properly.

Now I cannot see the panel anymore. This is how it should appear:

[image]

This, instead, is what I see in VS Code:

[image]

Normally, I would use these tools to access remote logs in the Azure Functions, but without **RESOURCES (Remote)** it seems no longer possible.

Comment: any update on this? Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @MatteoDeFelice In my case the solution was my answer reported below.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that, for some reasons, **RESOURCES (Remote)**, is not under the *Azure Tools* tab, but instead, it's under the *Explorer* tab.

In order to enable it, make sure you select **Resources** from the top right option tab:

[image]

This may be considered a workaround, rather than a solution, because it seems that all the screenshots found online, including the one attached to the question, have a **RESOURCES (Remote)** under the Azure Tools tab.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's this extension that you have been using:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-node-azure-pack

That extension is an **Extension Pack** which means it just installs multiple other extensions.

You could selectively install any of the 12 extensions that it includes from the marketplace directly.

e.g. You only need the Azure Functions extension for function logs:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions

Comment: Actually 'Azure Tools' is already installed, as well as 'Azure Function', 'Azure Resources' and other related stuff. I've tried to re-install them, enable/disable, but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: If they're already installed then try opening the command palette in vscode and typing `Azure: Sign Out` then `Azure: Sign In` again.

Comment: I've tried. I have 3 subscriptions, I've also tried to select and deselect them, but it doesn't help. It may just be that the RESOURCES (Remote) tab is disabled somewhere, but I've explored all the settings of all the related Azure extensions and I was not able to find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem where the Azure icon was not showing from the Activity Bar.
[image]

Found that to get this to show you must be in a Trusted workspace.  In the lower left corner of VS Code there was a notification that I was in "Restricted Mode"
[image]

Clicking this brought up another window
[image]

Click the Trust button and viola the Azure icon is now available.
[image]