# VS Code is not loading existing Azure Functions

Tags: python-3.x, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I deployed an Azure Function 2 months ago.
My VS Code was running perfectly according to my needs. Now I had to make some changes to my deployed function. but upon opening it is showing nothing.

Even from sidebar Azure extension it is not loading exiting azure functions. I tried everything, signin-signout, reinstalling, restarting, but nothing is working out for me. If I try to make a new function it asks me to create a new source although our company subscription is arleady listing in sidebar.

Can someone please help me in this regard?
Screenshot is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a lot of function apps deployed since many months and in recent days, but they are showing in the Visual Studio Code Azure Extension under Function App Resources.

[image: VSCodeAzureExtensionFunctionResources]

Few Steps to retrieve the existing resources in the VS Code Azure Extension are:

1. Uninstall and Install the [Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/extensions) like Azure Account, Azure Functions, Azure Resources, Azure Tools under Extensions blade:

[image]

2. Click on Settings (Gear Icon) > Make Sure your Microsoft Account is synced. If not, Sync it:

[image: SyncingAzureAccount]

3. Check one of the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72404848) given for similar issue by [@HAL9000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889762/hal9000)

Comment: Hi, I tried even reinstalling the vs code. but didn't work.
I removed everything related to vs code including caches and extensions from my pc and then it worked.
Thank you for kind words.

Comment: Sync on worked for me.  Odd that isn't standard.